# Why Session.Clear() - doesn't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, .net-core-2.1

I am using `.NET Core 2.1`, and trying to use Session as a part of authentication. What I am expecting to happen is:

1. Person logs in
2. I set the session value
3. Session cookie is returned
4. Person click log out
5. I clear the session by `HttpContext.Session.Clear()`

Then I am trying to fake a situation that the Session cookie has been stolen from the original person, so I create another request to the server, and expecting the value set in the session won't be there. It looks like it still holding it even after calling `Session.Clear()`.

Code:

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {     
          services.AddSession(options =>
          {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                options.Cookie.Name = SessionCookieName;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
          });
    }



    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseSession();
    }
```

**LogIn Action:**

```
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32(SessionConstants.Key, value);
```

**LogOut Action:**

```
HttpContext.Session.Clear();
```

**CheckLoginStatus Action:**

```
 var sessionValue = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(SessionConstants.Key);
```

**Test that revels problem:**

```
    var httpClientGenuineRequest = GetClient();
                var httpClientAttacker = GetClient();

                //Given
                var request = new LoginRequest()
                {
                   //filled properties
                };

                var loginResponse = await httpClientGenuineMember.PostAsync("urlToLoginAction", new JsonContent(request));
                AddResponseCookiesToHeaders(httpClientAttacker, loginResponse);

                await httpClientGenuineMember.PostAsync("urlToLogoutAction", new JsonContent(request));

                //When
                var response = await httpClientAttacker.GetAsync("urlToCheckStatusAction");

                //Here the actual result is true
                var actualResult = response.GetResult<bool>();

                //Then
                var expectedResult = false;
```

The above example isn't full. The question is with regards to Session values only, so I got rid of all other authentication code to make it more clear.

To me, it looks like, `HttpContext.Session.Clear` is not clearing the session, or the value is stored in the Session Cookie (which doesn't make any sense)?

Also when I debug through and check the Session value for my key, straight after `Clear()`, it gives me value null. But when I pass the Session cookie and try to read the value then, it is present again.

Obviously, when `Idle Timeout` runs out, the code behaves as expected. That sounds like a bit of a security risk during that time though.

Any help would be appreciated.

### EDIT:

According to the comment below the post, I tried to add the Redis session to it:

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(setup =>
            {
                setup.Configuration = "urlToRedisInstance";
                setup.InstanceName = "MySessionStateStore2";
            });
```

but the behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: Which session store do you use? (Sessions can be entirely stored in the session cookie too)

Comment: is that default behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging the code I found the problem:

The problem was in my tests. I was setting the Login request response cookies to the "attacker's" httpClient but not the actual user. As the result, it didn't get the `Session Cookie`, so my `Session.Clear()` actually cleared the newly created session, not the one that was created during the login process.

Corrected test:

```
var httpClientGenuineRequest = GetClient();
                var httpClientAttacker = GetClient();

                //Given
                var request = new LoginRequest()
                {
                   //filled properties
                };

                var loginResponse = await httpClientGenuineMember.PostAsync("urlToLoginAction", new JsonContent(request));
                AddResponseCookiesToHeaders(httpClientGenuineMember, loginResponse); // THAT LINE MADE THE DIFFERENCE
                AddResponseCookiesToHeaders(httpClientAttacker, loginResponse);

                await httpClientGenuineMember.PostAsync("urlToLogoutAction", new JsonContent(request));

                //When
                var response = await httpClientAttacker.GetAsync("urlToCheckStatusAction");

                //Here the actual result is true
                var actualResult = response.GetResult<bool>();

                //Then
                var expectedResult = false;
```

`Session.Clear()` works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is (as absurd as it sounds) is because you are not clearing the right session var.

according to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1) the session in .net core 2.1 ends when one of the following two scenarios occur:

> Session data is deleted either when the [ISession.Clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.isession.clear?view=aspnetcore-2.1) implementation
>   is called or when the session expires.

then the following states:

> There's no default mechanism to inform app code that a client browser
>   has been closed or when the session cookie is deleted or expired on
>   the client.

this is telling us two things:

**1)** if you want to use the session expired to the max, you will have to wright **on your own** the mechanism to inform your server when the client session expired or the browser closed. Else, you risk in keeping session data even when the browser is closed (this is an absurd situation, but one that exists).

**2)**  **ISession.Clear Method** is part of [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http?view=aspnetcore-2.1) name space, meaning that when you call `HttpContext.Session.Clear();` **you basically clear nothing at all.**

as I said, this situation can be a pain but is a living fact and one that our code must know how to handle if we choose to work with .net core 2.1 and session states.

Comment: I am not looking for clearing the session when the browser is closed, but when the user click LogOut button on site. I think if the user has the Session Cookie it should be enough to find right session and clear it. In regular .NET that would have been achieved by Session.Abandon(). Also it would be enough if I can get rid of the value in session with the Id that user has in their cookie, as the code checks if the particular value is in session.

Comment: however, you did not seem to get the right answer, I gave you two major scenarios regarding session state. One to determine when the session expires on the CLIENT side, the other is WHY YOUR SESSION IS NOT CLEARING. read the answer and the attached links as well please :)

Comment: I think you’re right, I miss-read it. I will test that today, instead of clear or remove the key will set the value to default for that key, as SetInt32 is extension from the correct namespace. If that works then, I need to implement my own clear mechanism, which would set the values, if there is not better way of doing it.

Comment: That answer helped me find the issue. Thank you very much.